# how to access in jquery parent parents class?

Tags: jquery

I want on page load for the class of a li tag to be removed...

HTML:

```
    <ul class="NewsArchive">
               <li class="off">
                    <a href="#" class="year">T's Blog</a>                
                        <ul class="NewsMonths" style="display: block; ">
                                   <li class="off">
                                    <a href="#" class="month">July 2011</a>              
                                        <ul class="BlogsArt" style="display: block; ">
                                               <li class="turnedon">
                                                   What's in a surname?
                                              </li>
                                    </ul>
                               </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="off">
                <a href="#" class="year">Steve's Blogs</a>                
                    <ul class="NewsMonths">
                               <li class="off">
                                <a href="#" class="month">February 2012</a>              
                                    <ul class="BlogsArt">
                                            <li>
                                                A bright note
                                            </li>
                                </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>  
           </li>
</ul>
```

what i want is for the li which has "turnedon" for its parent parent li class "off" to be rmoved. So the top off class. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$(function()
{
    $('li.turnedon').closest('li.off').removeClass('off');
});
```

This will remove the parents class `off` if it contains it.

```
$(function()
{
    $('li.turnedon').parents('li.off').removeClass('off');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$.parent()` and `$.removeClass` - simple ... if you want to remove all parents (recursively) you can use something like

```
var parent = $.parent(); // this needs to be called for the correct li object
do { 
    parent.removeClass('off')
    parent = parent.parent();
} while ( parent )
```